# Python Programming Class Definition

Tags: python

This is my code so far. In fact, I completed the requirements but the test made it harder when checking the result by requiring my code to be more flexible with the 'person' I made. I've been stuck on this for about 2 days so I really hope someone can help me make my code more flexible by being able to change people and their birthdate just as the extra requirements.

```
 from datetime import date

class person:
    pass

def create_person(name, height, birthdate):
    person.name = name
    person.height = height
    person.age = birthdate
    return person

def get_age(person):
    birthdate = date(1976, 8, 14)
    today = date.today()
    age = today.year - birthdate.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (birthdate.month, birthdate.day))
    return age

def get_description(person):
    return person.name + ' is ' + str(person.height) + ' cm high and is ' + str(get_age(person)) + ' years old.'

def main():
    birthdate = date(1976, 8, 14)
    person = create_person('Michael', 190, birthdate)
    print(get_description(person))
```

> This is the question I got:
>
> Write a class definition for the Person class and write user-defined
> functions with these function headers:
>
> ```
> def create_person(name, height, birthdate):
>   # Return a a new person object with the given
>   # name, height and birthdate.
>   # - name is a str
>   # - height is an int object in centimetres
>   # - birthdate is a date object from the
>   # module datetime
>
> def get_age(person):
>   # Return the age of the person in years. For example, assume today's date is June 12, 2022. if Mary was born on June 4, 2020, then
> ```
>
> Mary's age is 2. However, if Bob was born on June 14, 2020, then Bob
> would not have had a second birthday yet so the age is 1.
>
> ```
> def get_description(person):
>   # Return a string object of the form: Name is
>   # N cm high and is M years old, where N and M For example, if Michael's height is 190cm and his age is 45, the string object
> ```
>
> returned from this function should be:  Michael is 190 cm high and is
> 46 years old.
>
> ```
> def main():
>   # Create a person named 'Michael', with height
>   # 190 cm, who was born on August 14, 1976 and
>   # output a description of this individual.
>       # are integers Here is a sample run of a main program that just calls the main function.
>
> Michael is 190 cm high and is 46 years old.
> ```

And this is a hint I received:

> Use the date class from the datetime module to represent a date. An
> object whose type is date, has attributes: year, month and day that
> you can use to compute the age of a Person.
>
> To compute the current age of a person, you will need to first compute
> today's date. There is a method in the date class of the datetime
> module that creates a new date object that represents the current
> date. The name of this method is today. However, the special argument
> of this method must be the date class itself, instead of a particular
> object whose type is date. A method that is applied to a class object
> instead of to an instance of that class is called a class method.
>
> Therefore, to create the current date you can use the expression:
>
> `date.today()`
>
> since after importing the date class from the datetime module, the
> identifier date is bound to the date class object.
>
> To compute the age you can just subtract the year attribute of the
> birthdate from the year attribute of the current date. However, you
> will also need to check whether the person has already had their
> birthday yet this year and if not, subtract one year

**And this is the result when I test my following code:**

```
#TEST 1#
main() returned None
inputs:

outputs:
Michael is 190 cm high and is 46 years old.
----------
#TEST 2#
** ERROR **get_description(sara) returned Georgia is 170 cm high and is 46 years old.
* EXPECTED * Sara is 160 cm high and is 20 years old.
inputs:

outputs:
----------
#TEST 3#
** ERROR **get_age(sara) returned 46
* EXPECTED * 20
inputs:

outputs:
----------
#TEST 4#
** ERROR **get_age(eric) returned 46
* EXPECTED * 10
inputs:

outputs:
----------
#TEST 5#
** ERROR **get_age(carter) returned 46
* EXPECTED * 11
inputs:

outputs:
----------
#TEST 6#
** ERROR **get_age(georgia) returned 46
* EXPECTED * 14
inputs:

outputs:
----------
```

Comment: What's the point of the class if all the "methods" are defined outside of it?

Comment: The class *itself* serves the purpose of your `create_person` function; you should probably read the [section of the tutorial on classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html). Whoever wrote this assignment is doing you a disservice. (Or one can hope that this is just a lead-in to how the class should *really* be defined.)

Comment: You didn't use `class` correctly here. It's a pretty good attempt but the syntax and use of classes is very off, because the class you built is empty. The problem is that you aren't creating instances of `people`, you're just creating and modifying `class attributes` rather than `instance attributes` Your method was bizarre but understandable, but the problem is that with this only one person can be stored at a time because no instances are created, and creating a new person will delete all information about the person you previously tried to create.

Comment: That's why only one set of values has been saved and in the test run only info about `Georgia` is being output.

Answer (score 2):

`create_person()` needs to create an instance of the `Person` class, not assign attributes of the class itself. Otherwise you can only have one person -- you're using the class as a global variable.

```
class Person:
    pass

def create_person(name: str, height: int, birthdate: datetime.date) -> Person:
    person = Person()
    person.name = name
    person.height = height
    person.age = birthdate
    return person
```

Note that this is an unusual way to define the class. Normally you would initialize the attributes in the class's `__init__()` method.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name: str, height: int, birthdate: datetime.date):
        self.name = name
        self.height = height
        self.age = birthdate

def create_person(name: str, height: int, birthdate: datetime.date) -> Person:
    return Person(name, height, age)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to create the Person() object inside the create_person function. This code worked well:

```
    from datetime import date
    
    class Person:
        pass
    
    def create_person(name, height, birthdate):
        person = Person()
        person.name = name
        person.height = height
        person.age = birthdate
        return person
    
    def get_age(person):
        birthdate = person.age
        today = date.today()
        age = today.year - birthdate.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (birthdate.month, birthdate.day))
        return age
    
    def get_description(person):
        return person.name + ' is ' + str(person.height) + ' cm high and is ' + str(get_age(person)) + ' years old.'
    
    def main():
        birthdate = date(1976, 8, 14)
        person = create_person('Michael', 190, birthdate)
        print(get_description(person))
```